# How to get the return type and the generic type of the return type of current method being executed in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, asp.net-web-api2, system.reflection

I have this code

```
    [HttpPost("search")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<int>> GetEmployees([FromBody] EmployeeSearchDto employeeSearchParameters)
    {

    }
```

How to get

ActionResult type and

int type

I can't seem to find the return type property in reflections.

**Additional Information:**

The problem that I am trying to solve

I am using mediator in which response is determined on runtime.

I have this method

```
    public Task<ActionResult<ListDto<EmployeeListItemDto>>> GetEmployees([FromBody] EmployeeSearchDto employeeSearchParameters)
    {
        var request = new GetEmployeesQuery()
        {
            EmployeeSearchParameters = employeeSearchParameters
        };

        var response = await _mediator.Send(request).ConfigureAwait(false); //this  returns a response is determined in runtime due to mediatr that contains a property Ienumerable<T> T as employee


        return base.ProcessResponse(response); //this returns and ObjectResult with values from the database
    }
```

The problem is that when we replaced the return type

```
Task<ActionResult<ListDto<EmployeeListItemDto>>>
```

to

```
Task<ActionResult<int>>
```

it still runs and Swagger shows 0 as success response due to int return type.

I was asked if we could have a way to prevent this,

I figured comparing the return type of response.ResponseValues which returns IEnumerable

and ActionResult if they are equal on runtime.

Basically what we are trying to accomplish is typesafety which I don't know is possible so I resorted to reflection.

**Update** 
I tried to use RB's solution, but not sure how to use it.

```
public Task<ActionResult<ListDto<EmployeeListItemDto>>> GetEmployees([FromBody] EmployeeSearchDto employeeSearchParameters)
{
    var request = new GetEmployeesQuery()
    {
        EmployeeSearchParameters = employeeSearchParameters
    };

    var response = await _mediator.Send(request).ConfigureAwait(false); //this  returns a response is determined in runtime due to mediatr that contains a property Ienumerable<T> T as employee
GetMethodInfo(GetEmployees); //Im getting cannot be inferred from the usage error.


    return base.ProcessResponse(response); //this returns and ObjectResult with values from the database
}

    public Type GetMethodInfo<T>(Func<T> foo)
    {
        return foo.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
    }
```

Im getting cannot be inferred from the usage error

Comment: use `Task<IActionResult>`.  There is no need to specify the return  type. `return Ok(result)` where result is the object you want to return.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because you didn't show your attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: That's not answering my question though. Im asking given an executed function. How do you get the return type/generic return type of the method currently being executed on runtime. Tried reflection can't find any ReturnType property.

Comment: If you can use reflection to get the `MethodInfo`, that object will have a `ReturnType` property. From there, do some research on how to get the generic parameter of the return type.

Comment: I don't know much about ASP.NET, but I think what these people are telling you is that you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) - you are trying to solve a problem in a way that you think will work, but in actuality that's a terrible way of doing it. So maybe you could tell us more about the _actual_ problem that you are trying to solve? i.e. _Why_ do you want these types?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the return type of the method currently executing, you need to cast the response of `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` to a `MethodInfo`.

```
var method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();

var returnType = ((MethodInfo)method).ReturnType;

// You can now inspect the return type as a normal Type.
```

### EDIT - Async support

The above code does not work for an `async` method. However, you can use another method to obtain the correct value:

```
public async Task<int> Bob()
{
    var returnType = Utilities.GetMethodInfo(Bob);
    // returnType == typeof(Task<Int32>) 

    return 5;
}

public static class Utilities
{
    public static Type GetMethodInfo<T>(Func<T> foo)
    {
        return foo.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this one

Comment: @AndrewMcmellan Just to be clear though - this is *how* you would do it - it would be very useful if you would explain *why* you wanted to do it to ensure there is not a better approach - the framework is a swiss-army knife for skinning cats after all (if that's not too tortured a metaphor) :)

Comment: For some reason its returning System.Void when im expecting Task<ActionResult<int>>.

Comment: @andrewmcmellan Please could you explain in what way it doesn't work? It *will* get you the return type of the currently executing method, which is what I understood you were after. Does it give you an incorrect answer, or a compile error, or a runtime error?

Comment: @andrewmcmellan oh, you are right. It's because your method is async (I tested with a non async method - apologies)

Comment: I added additional information to the problem that I am trying to solve

Comment: @AndrewMcmellan I've added another approach that *does* work for `async` methods. Does this work for you?

Comment: I'll try this one

Comment: Sorry but could you help me out on how I should use this?

Comment: I tried using your solution. I updated my post to add use code. im getting an error

Comment: Ah - you will need a `Func<T1, T>` instead of `Func<T>` as your method has 1 parameter.

Comment: I dont get it what do I pass as T1 and T? Im using it like this GetMethodInfo(GetEmployees); its showing error